# Bundle Angular 2 app with Systemjs an Gulp - Sub folders

Tags: angular, gulp

Hi I'm working with an Angular 2 project downloaded from [here](https://github.com/Anjmao/angular2-production-workflow)

What the original does is takes all files from the app folder, compiles to typescript, bundles them and the places them in the dist folder.

The only problem is that, I have sub folders and files, within the app folder which it does not bundle in anyway and so, throws errors.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///profile.component.html

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');
var builder = new Builder('', 'systemjs.config.js');

var bundleHash = new Date().getTime();
var mainBundleName = bundleHash + '.main.bundle.js';
var vendorBundleName = bundleHash + '.vendor.bundle.js';

// This is main task for production use
gulp.task('dist', function(done) {
    runSequence('clean', 'compile_ts', 'bundle', 'copy_assets', function() {
        done();
    });
});

gulp.task('bundle', ['bundle:vendor', 'bundle:app'], function () {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            'app': mainBundleName,
            'vendor': vendorBundleName
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('bundle:vendor', function () {
    return builder
        .buildStatic('app/vendor.js', './dist/' + vendorBundleName)
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Vendor bundle error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});

gulp.task('bundle:app', function () {
    return builder
        .buildStatic('app/main.js', './dist/' + mainBundleName)
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('App bundle error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});

gulp.task('compile_ts', ['clean:ts'], shell.task([
    'tsc'
]));

gulp.task('copy_assets', function() {
     return gulp.src(['./assets/**/*'], {base:"."})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', ['clean:ts', 'clean:dist']);

gulp.task('clean:dist', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./dist'], {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('clean:ts', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/**/*.js', './app/**/*.js.map'], {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});
```

I apologise I'm quite new to this